# How to print Global errors only with form:errors?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my form, i have some specific targeted errors (with `path="myField"`) and i'd like to throw global errors, because they span multiple fields.

But if i use `<form:errors path="*">`, it will print global AND re-print local errors !

How can i print only the global ones ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I remember, you need to use `<form:errors />` without `path` attribute to do it.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure about using `form` tag to do that. But `Errors` object has methods to [getglobalerrors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#getGlobalErrors%28%29).

**EDIT**

```
    <spring:hasBindErrors name="input">
            <c:forEach items="${errors.globalErrors}" var="errorMessage">
                <div id="errors" class="errors">
                        <c:out value="${errorMessage.defaultMessage}" />
                </div>
            </c:forEach>
    </spring:hasBindErrors>
```

Answer (score 0):

omitting path does not work,
you must insert empty path:

```
<form:errors path=""/>
```