# Use error in form without a field binding?

Tags: java, validation, jsp, forms, spring-mvc

I am wondering whether you can use a <form:errors> tag to display an error that doesn't have a binding to a field in the command object. Basically I want to do some custom validation logic that isn't directly related to a single form element, but perhaps many or all, or none. What if I only wanted to validate forms from 9am to 3pm?

I tried creating a global error like Errors.reject("myError"), but then how do I put this in the jsp? Must I make an attribute just for this in the command object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692323/how-to-print-global-errors-only-with-formerrors

Comment: Oops! Sorry I searched but I guess I didn't see the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Spring Errors you have the choice to use it for:

- errors for an specific field in the command object, but this field **must** exist.
- global errors, that are not associated to any field.

To access global errors in the JSP, you could use `<form:errors />` without `path` attribute or you can access the error variable in a direct way: (@see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/taglib/tag/BindErrorsTag.html for a list of variables)

To enable the validation only between 9am to 3pm you need to implement you own validator.